# Laravel Routing To subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am using **Laravel 5.7**. Currently have all the route go through `Api.php`, `web.php`, and `website.php`. In live version of the app, there is a subdomain pointing to `website.php` is `[anything].websiteaddress.com`, and domain `www.websiteaddress.com` is pointing `web.php`. In local environment, how can I access subdomain using `localhost:8000`. I have tried to use `[anything].websiteaddress.com`, it does not work. What is proper way to access subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Configure in Web server 
**httpd.conf**
create virual Host ip or name what you want

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName website.com

 ServerAlias *.website.com

</VirtualHost>
```

2.route configuration like

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.website.com'), function() {

    Route::get('/', function($account, $id) {
        // ...
        return Redirect::to('https://www.website.com'.'/'.$account);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://lvh.me:8000.

**lvh.me** is a free service that resolves itself with all subdomains to `localhost`.

There’s nothing to install or run. If you want to test the `example` subdomain all you have to do is go to http://example.lvh.me:8000 and it would work.

It even works without subdomains too. For example, if you have an app running at [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000) on your dev box, you could go to [lvh.me:8000](http://lvh.me:8000) to load it.

You can try also http://vcap.me:8000 and http://localtest.me:8000 they all resolve to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Comment: this does not work well with browsersync which is very important